# Ajaxsubmitbutton Not Passing ID

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, yii

I have a problem using bootstrap modal for updating data.

On CGridView selectionChanged, it will trigger a function to show modal dialog form and insert the data to the form

Here is my CGridView :

```
<?php
    $this->widget('customCGridView', array(
                    'id'=>'contactperson-grid',
                    'itemsCssClass' => 'table table-bordered',
                    'selectionChanged'=>'showmodal',
                    'dataProvider' => $contactperson->search(),
                    'emptyText' => '',
                    'enableSorting' => false,
                    'htmlOptions' => array('class' => ' '),
                    'columns' => array('nama', 'jabatan')
    ));
?>
```

On selectionChanged, it will trigger this script to open the update dialog modal and fill the form with selected CGridView column data :

```
function showmodal(grid_id) {     
    var keyId = $.fn.yiiGridView.getSelection(grid_id);
    keyId  = keyId[0]; //above function returns an array with single item, so get the value of the first item     
  $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo $this->createUrl("suppliertable/personview"); ?>',
        data: {id: keyId},
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            $("#contact-person-modal").html(data);
            $('#kontakmodalupdate').modal('show');
        }
    });
 }
```

Here is the actionPersonView which will be executed upon selecting column :

```
public function actionPersonView($id) {                
    $contactperson = SupplierContactPersonTable::model()->findByPk($id);
    if ($contactperson === null)
        throw new CHttpException(404, 'The requested page does not exist.');

    $this->renderPartial('updateForm', array('contactperson'=> $contactperson));              
    Yii::app()->end();
}
```

Now, here is the problem :

When I Click update button on update form, I need to pass ID to my action :

```
public function actionPersonUpdate($id) {
    $model2=$this->loadModel2($id);                    

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['SupplierContactPersonTable']))
    {
        if($model2 === null) {
            throw new CHttpException(404, 'The requested page does not exist.');
        }

        $model2->attributes=$_POST['SupplierContactPersonTable'];
        $model2->save();
    }
}
```

To pass this value, I'm using AjaxButton on my form:

```
<div id="contact-person-modal">
<?php
    $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
                      'id' => 'suppliercontactmodalform',
                      'htmlOptions' => array(
                                          'class' => 'smart-form',
                                          'novalidate' => '1',),
                      'enableAjaxValidation' => false,));
?>

...

<footer>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-labeled btn-danger cancel-button" style="float: left">
        Hapus Pengguna
    </button>
    <?php
       echo CHtml::ajaxButton('Update', Yii::app()->createUrl('suppliertable/personupdate',array('id'=>$contactperson->contact_person_id)), array('type'=>'POST'), array('type'=>'submit',"class" => "btn btn-primary"));

    ?>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
    Batal
    </button>    
</footer>
...
```

However, it seems like ID isn't passed. Here is Firebug console :

```
POST http://localhost/webapp/index.php/suppliertable/personupdate/
400 Bad Request
```

As you can see, no ID is passed.

But, if I use static parameter value :

```
echo CHtml::ajaxButton('Update', Yii::app()->createUrl('suppliertable/personupdate',array('id'=>'5')), array('type'=>'POST'), array('type'=>'submit',"class" => "btn btn-primary"));
```

The ID is passed :

```
POST http://localhost/webapp/index.php/suppliertable/personupdate/5
```

So, I think the problem is here, is not outputing value :

```
$contactperson->contact_person_id
```

Here is generated jQuery from Yii :

```
jQuery('body').on('click','#yt0',function({
    jQuery.ajax({
        'type':'POST',
        'url':'/webapp/index.php/suppliertable/personupdate id=',
        'cache':false,
        'data':jQuery(this).parents("form").serialize()
    });
    return false;
});
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Please inspect the network tab. The url address contains a `?id=`, but it's using a `POST`, and the URL parse would be for a GET. What we need to see if the `POST` request is hitting the server by checking the network tab and looking at the value of `data`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Here is the result from network tab :

`POST personupdate?id=`

And from the params tab :

`id`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Have update the code, maybe it is easier to identify my problem :)

Comment: try changing  url: '<?php echo $this->createUrl('suppliertable/personview'); ?>' to  url: '<?php echo $this->createUrl("suppliertable/personview"); ?>'

Comment: @ViPiN Hv done that, still the result is 
`POST http://localhost/webapp/index.php/suppliertable/personupdate/
400 Bad Request`. I updated the code

Comment: Did you check your model after findByPk($id) ? $contactperson = SupplierContactPersonTable::model()->findByPk($id);  try to print your model

Comment: @sany2k8 I think the model is Ok, because I have inserted an exception if $contactperson === null then it will throw 404 error. But in this case, 400 error is thrown instead. I think it has something to do with the jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my solution.

In case someone have the same problem, I need to update my actionPersonView method :

```
public function actionPersonView($id) {
            if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest) {
                Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap['jquery.js'] = false;
                Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap['jquery.min.js'] = false;   
                $contactperson = SupplierContactPersonTable::model()->findByPk($id);

                if ($contactperson === null)
                    throw new CHttpException(404, 'The requested page does not exist.');

                $this->renderPartial('updateForm', array('contactperson'=> $contactperson),false,true);              
                Yii::app()->end();
            }
    }
```

I need to add in my actionPersonView method

```
$this->renderPartial('updateForm', array('contactperson'=> $contactperson),false,true);
```

And add

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap['jquery.js'] = false;
Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap['jquery.min.js'] = false;
```

To prevent the script being executed multiple.